# Configuring SSO utilizing ADFS 2.0, SAML 2.0, and simpleSAMLphp

Tags: saml, http-status-code-401, adfs2.0

My knowledge of these systems is not large so please forgive me if I am asking dumb questions.

I hope to achieve the following:

Idp (AD FS 2.0) -> SAML 2.0 -> Sp (simpleSAMLphp)

*I don't need anything more fancy than to simply authenticate a user.

I have attempted to configure Windows Server 2008 with AD FS 2.0 (domain A) as an Identity provider and have it handle authentication requests from a service provider on a different domain (created using simpleSAMLphp (domain B)).

The AD FS 2.0 Management application allows me to add raw meta XML from the SP to configure the idp. And my SP has the facility to do the same. So I figure that If I setup the idp (AD FS 2.0) correctly then I will simple just have to make the SP interpret the metadata of the idp.

Currently I feel that I am close to a solution (but then again I am probably wrong!). Currently it seems everything is find right up to the point when the Idp asks for your login credentials, and I enter my credentials, it appears that the session has started, but I get a 'Not Authorized - HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.' message after entering the correct login credentials.

Could someone please explain how to fix this? or if it's quicker a step by step setup to make AD FS 2.0 authenticate using SAML 2.0 for simply authenticating a username and password.

Thankyou in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Have you established a claims provider trust within ADFS 2.0 management? Your system needs to accept claims-bearing tokens from a trusted claims provider. That is, whatever STS -- "Security Token Service" -- you have in front of your user repository. ADFS can both a "Relying Party" -- RP -- or a STS. You need both a relying party and a STS.

Check out Eugenio Pace's MSDN blog for more details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/tags/federated+identity/